# Sequelize -> Object Sequelize Instance

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, handlebars.js

it is my first question here, sorry any disorganization.

*ControlerTable.js*

```
async function index(req,res){

let data = await table.findAll();

return res.render('index', {entrada:data});
}
```

Habdlebars
*list.handlebars*

```
{{#extend "head"}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/list.css"/>
{{/extend}}


{{#each entrada}}
<div class="entrada-div">
    <div>{{../day}}</div>
    <div>{{../entrada}}</div>
    <div>{{../saida}}</div>
    <div>{{../lucro}}</div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

*Index.handlebars*

```
{{>formulario}}
{{>list entrada = entrada}}
```

*Output*
[image: output]

My issues are the sequelize is returning a object when should return a valor.

Comment: Please paste the code you tried instead of the screenshot. :)

Comment: thanks for edit Harshana, I will paste